# Unconfirmed Transactions on Balance and History

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, copay

Is there any way to see the unconfirmed transactions within the balance of the CoPay's Bitcoin Wallet and get notifications when it receives an unconfirmed transaction?
Because I didn't see my transaction and had to search it in the blockchain to be sure that it exists .. and I remember that some other wallets already do this with an UNCONFIRMED tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable this feature in copay settings:

[image]